# Tailwind css is not being served in Django App

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css, django-tailwind

I've been working on this Tailwind+Django project and it was working fine. Now it's not serving css. I've run the commanands ***py manage.py runserver*** and ***py manage.py tailwind start*** and there's no problem on servers.
here is Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authen.CustomUser'

TAILWIND_APP_NAME = 'theme'
INTERNAL_IPS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
]
NPM_BIN_PATH = r"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd"
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("__reload__/", include("django_browser_reload.urls")),
    path('',include('authen.urls')),
    path('rental/',include('rental.urls')),
    path('roommate/',include('roommate.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        '../templates/**/*.html',

        '../../templates/**/*.html',

        '../../**/templates/**/*.html',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
        require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
        require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    ],
}
```

here is the project structure

[image]

Thanks for your time. if any further information is needed please ask.

Comment: as I remeber normally Django doesn't server `static` files like `.js`, `,css`, `images` and you have to configure Apache, Nginx or other WWW server to serve static files.